# What do you call the collection of types that obeys certain constraints?

Tags: haskell, types, terminology, definition

Given a function

```
f :: Vector a => a -> b
```

we would call `a` a type (or type variable), and `Vector` a constraint.  But what do we call the collection of all types that satisfy `Vector a => a`?  I've been informally calling it "the set of Vector spaces" and I call any member type a "Vector space".  Are there more accurate type-theoretic names I should be using?  In particular, are the words "set" and "space" used correctly?

Comment: I usually call them "instances of `Vector`", and since we're limited to the category of `Hask` when programming in Haskell you could say "the set of instances of `Vector`", although "set" is too limiting a term in general category theory.

Comment: For me it's just a (dependent) function. Class constraints pretty much always desugar into functions in core type theories. Operationally `Vector a => a` is also just a function. Part of the reason why we have the monomorphism restriction is to remind people of that.

Comment: Sometimes I like to think that "type class" stands for "the class of types such and such". I'm not sure if this is the actual meaning that originated the term.

Comment: @AndrásKovács I interpret the question to be about "the collection of all types `a` that satisfy the `Vector a` constraint", but your comment to be about "the inhabitants of the particular type `Vector a => a`" -- which are very different beasts.

Comment: @chi, that seems a very reasonable interpretation to me. There seems to be an analogy to class-based set theories—types are "elements" of classes, and the class language is much more limited than the type language. Set theory, however, typically admits (binary) unions of classes, whereas I don't think that notion makes sense in Haskell.

Comment: Whether or not the "vector space" part is appropriate depends on which `Vector` class you're talking about.